# Jackson How to retrieve parent bean in a custom Serializer/Deserializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

In a custom serializer/deserializer, is there a way to retrieve the parent bean of the field?

For example:

```
public class Foo {

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
    public Bar bar;

}

public class Bar { }

public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bar> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(
        Bar value, 
        JsonGenerator jgen, 
        SerializerProvider serializers) 
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
    {
        // get Foo ??
    }
}
```

Here I'd like to get `Foo` in my serializer without having to have a reference inside `Bar`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Jackson 2.5, it is possible to access parent object via `JsonGenerator.getCurrentValue()`. Or, further up the hierarchy, going via `getOutputContext()` (which has `getParent()` as well as `getCurrentValue()` method).
This is also available through `JsonParser` for custom deserializer.

Comment: No mechanism that I can think of.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm always getting null on `JsonGenerator.getCurrentValue()`, any idea why?

Comment: @rbajales there may be gaps for older versions, so one thing to make sure is to use latest patch (2.6.4). Custom serializers might also not set the current value, as it is up to serializers for set it appropriately for nested types.

Answer (score 7):

For deserialization, where you don't have access to the `JsonGenerator` object. The following worked for me:

```
JsonStreamContext parsingContext = jsonParser.getParsingContext();
JsonStreamContext parent = parsingContext.getParent();
Object currentValue = parent.getCurrentValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: getCurrentValue will be null if you are using custom serialization

I worked around this by setting the parent object into the child's serializer instance and then accessing it when the child's serializer was called by jackson.